# Binding SSL certificate to a new site, changes other's certificate

Tags: ssl, iis, certificate

I just created a new SSL certificate with GoDaddy. I imported this certificate into IIS 8.0.
Then I checked all existing sites and their SSL certificate. Everyone has its own certificate. So far, so good.

Now I want to add the new imported certificate to a new site. But everytime when I do this, an "error" comes and says that there is an existing site that uses the same certificate. But before that I checked all sites and I haven't seen the same certificate.

If I click on "do it anyway" it changes the certificate of an other site to the new certificate that I just imported. So as a result two sites are using the same certificate now.

How can that happen? Is there a possibility that these two sites have a kind of a connection? Did I do something wrong with the import?

I absolutely have no idea.

Thank you.

PS: Even if I apply for a new certificate, I still get the same result.

PS: Could it be because of two different SSL distributors? One is Symantec and the other one is GoDaddy.

PS: This is the first GoDaddy certificate that I try to install after the Symantec one.

Comment: You might use Jexus Manager to review HTTP API settings before making a change, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/https-binding.html so as to avoid any possible conflict.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be using the same IP and port for all the url's configured on IIS 8. If that's the case, then you have to mention the exact URL in the Hostname section when you bind the certificate as per image below.

Also Make sure you put a tick mark to REQUIRE SERVER NAME INDICATION and then select the correct certificate from the dropdown in the SSL Certificate section.

[image]

Comment: Still applies on IIS 10. Just ticking Require Server Name Indication fixed it for me.